# table row if input element consists

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

There is a table, how I can get `tr` (table row), if there consists at least one `input` element.

I tried like:

```
$('#tablename:contains(input)').closest('tr');
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe `$('#tablename tr input').closest('tr')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#tablename tr:has(input)')
```

is what you were looking for.

- Read about the [:has() selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).
- `:contains()` will look for simple text, while `:has()` will look for elements that match the selector.

Or the [**more efficient version**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/#notes-0):

```
$('#tablename tr').has('input')
```

- Read about [.has() filter function](http://api.jquery.com/has/).
- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sNNW3/)

Comment: Nice! To take it a step further how would I check for a specific value for the input?

Comment: @Alex I guess the `filter()` would be useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to explain what you're trying to do a bit better. If you find that

```
$('#tablename').find(":input").val();
```

it works only when you have one input, maybe what you're looking for is this:

```
  $('#tablename').find(":input").each(function() {
     // Prints the value of each input.
    alert($(this).val());
   }
```

Comment: The OP wants the `tr`s, no the inputs: `how I can get tr (table row)`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$('#tablename tr input').closest('tr')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
 $('#tablename input').closest('tr');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this `$('#tablename:has(input)').find('tr')`

I hope you will find this usefull!!

Answer (score -1):

This must helps:

```
$('#tablename input').parentsUntil('tr');
```

Comment: This will select everything between the `tr` and the `input`, but not the `tr` itself.